# Parse the ouput of a variable

Tags: python

I have the following variable,i need to parse the value in ErrorMessage,can anyone suggest how to get it?

```
message ={"Value":1,"ErrorMessage":null,"Text":{"Result":"<RequestGroupID>11647</RequestGroupID><RequestID>34382</RequestID>"}}

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a JSON string. You need to use `json.loads` to parse it and convert it into a dictionary first.

```
import json
ob = json.loads(message)
print(ob["ErrorMessage"])
```

Though this will give you `None`, not `null`.